# D3.js nested items sharing the same data

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around d3.js nested elements.

I'm trying to make some simple horizontal bar charts, with a 100% with background (container).
Something like this :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cticjxi7e6x8ujy/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-12-06%2014.32.56.png?dl=0

I'm picturing the generated markup this way :

```
<div class="bar-legend-container">
    <div class="bar-legend-data"></div>
</div>
```

With the .bar-legend-data width changing with the data.
Pretty simple.

So, using D3.js, I'm appending a .bar-legend-container for every of my data elements.Then, I'm trying to append the .bar-legend-data inside, using the container's data. And that's where it doesn't work.

Here is a jsfiddle of the exact issue :
http://jsfiddle.net/d72hqq0n/1/

**I've tried simpler way to do it**, like just appending the inner element straight away, which worked, but didn't update on data change.

**So, my exact questions would be :**

- How can I append two nested elements sharing the same data with d3.js ? And make both of same update if the data changes ?
- Why is my code isn't working ? What am I missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that DOM elements can inherit data from their parent. You can also create the nested element when you create its parent.

The result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/d72hqq0n/5/

You had a bit of a run-in with an advanced feature, [grouping elements](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#group). Basically, if you call `container.selectAll(".bar-legend-container").selectAll(".bar-legend-data")`, you've created a group of elements as the first element of the selection. This can mess up data bindings if you don't know what you're doing. The solution is to use `barContainer.select(".bar-legend-data")` rather than `selectAll`. Doing so just replaces the containers with the bars themselves in the selection. It also propagates the data from the parent (`append` does that too, but only when the bars are created!).

The other bug I encountered was that values "pulse" paste the end before settling on their new values. This seems to be a bug where `800px` is being treated as `800%` for interpolation purposes. This was addressed at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396470) but the solution doesn't help us since it destroys the elements and resets them to 0. Instead, I had to reach outside the D3 API to grab the width of the parent element, and go by that.

We both may have fallen down a rabbit hole, but I learned a lot researching this answer, so thank you. Hopefully this was helpful to you.