# How to control transition percent with d3js?

Tags: d3.js

For example, there is a rect. It's width is 10, and will change to 100.

The code is like this:

```js
d3.select("#bar")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("width", 100);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect id="bar" x="50" y="50" height="10" width="10" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Expect that could use a input range to control the transition like this:
(The code below just show what expect. Just run it and no need to understand)

```js
function handleChangeRange(e) {
  const val = this.progress.value
  this.result.value = val
  document.getElementById('bar').style.setProperty('--process', val / 100)
}
```

```css
@keyframes animation-line {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.line {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.animating {
  animation-name: animation-line;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--process) * -3s);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.auto-play {
  display: none;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

input[name="autoPlay"]:checked ~ input[name="progress"],
input[name="autoPlay"]:checked ~ output[name="result"],
input[name="autoPlay"]:checked ~ .animating:not(.auto-play) {
  display: none;
}

input[name="autoPlay"]:checked ~ .animating.auto-play {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form oninput="handleChangeRange.call(this, event)">
    <!-- auto play -->
    <input name="autoPlay" id="autoPlay" type="checkbox">
    <label for="autoPlay">auto play</label>
    <div class="line animating auto-play"></div>

    <!-- control timeline -->
    <div id="bar" class="line animating" style="--process:1;"></div>
    <input name="progress" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.1" value="100" />
    <output name="result">100</output>
</form>
```

When drag the input range. This shows how width change to 100 from 10.
When checked auto play, it will play the animation and hide the control UI.

I'm using d3.js to make a animation more complex. So the css can't help me.

Thank you for reading the question!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398793/7534433 is close what expect.
The answer demo is http://jsfiddle.net/8vGm7/6

However, it plays whole transition from the specified position.

Comment: By the way, how to insert code snippet when ask question, not asked and edit.